# Integers and while loop in C++... how?

Tags: c++

I.e, i have this code:

```
int main {
   cin >> x;
    while (x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3) {
        cout << "Invalid input, try again!" << endl;
        cin >> x;
    }
    cout << "Hello, World";
}
```

It should return "Hello, World" when the integer variable "x" is 1, 2 or 3.

But, when i type a non-integer value (i.e. "Hello"), why it will go in loop?

Comment: You have to check error after `std::cin >>` (and reset it).

Comment: Look at [error-handling-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824921/error-handling-in-c)

Comment: Can you show us where you define `x`?

Comment: Please try to learn the correct terminology. It shouldn't _"return"_ "Hello, World", but _"print"_ it. This is a crucial difference and sticking to correct terminology improves your question which most likely leads to better answers. Cheers!

Comment: @QuestionsMan Do you initialize `x` to anything?

Comment: Nope, but i have already tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you define and initialize `x`, it may go into the loop every time you enter a non-integer, or it may only go into the loop sometimes.

If you don't assign any value to `x`, then the value of `x` is still undefined after `cin >> x` if you enter a non-integer, because conversion failed and therefore no value is written to `x`.  So `x` could be literally any number, and you have undefined behavior in your program.  It may enter the loop sometimes and other times it may not.

If you assign something like 0 to `x` initially, then the value of `x` will still be 0 if conversion fails, because it is not changed, and therefore the loop condition would be true and the loop would be entered.

One option would be to only loop if the conversion succeeded, which you could do like this:

```
int main(void) {
    while ((cin >> x) && x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3) {
        cout << "Invalid input, try again!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Hello, World";
    return 0;
}
```

`cin >> x` will return `cin`, which evaluates to false in boolean context if an error condition was encountered (EOF, failed conversion, etc.).