# infinite loop for decimal number only

Tags: c++, function, loops, while-loop, infinite

So basically I am trying to develop a simple application that uses a function to determine whether from 2 numbers input by a user, the second number is a multiple of the first.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int multiple( int n1, int n2){
    if(n1%n2 ==0)return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main(){
    int num1, num2;
    cout<<"Enter 2 numbers (-1 to exit): ";
    cin>>num1>>num2;
    while (num1 !=-1 && num2 != -1){
        if (multiple (num1, num2)==1)cout<<num2<<" is a multiple of "<<num1<<endl<<endl;
        else cout<<num2<<" is not a multiple of "<<num1<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter 2 numbers (-1 to exit): ";
        cin>>num1>>num2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I try it with normal integers it works fine,but why is it that when I input the second number as a decimal, it enters an infinite loop? Specifically this is the statement it keeps giving:

> "Enter 2 numbers (-1 to exit): 1 is a multiple of 0"

The debugger shows that `num1` becomes `0` for some weird reason. I know I can overcome this by using an if statement, but for my own curiosity can anybody out there explain why this happens? I can provide you with any other thing you require, and I am using `xCode` if that is of any relevance.

Comment: What do you think `cin >> num1 >> num2` does when you type something that isn't an integer? What does it put in the variables?

Comment: The dot prevents reading the next integer. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283302/user-input-of-integers-error-handling) question and answers, it may help in your case as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++, getting a infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002137/c-getting-a-infinite-loop)

Comment: wouldn't it round it down, so for instance if I input 2.5, wont it store it as 2?

Comment: @user3311681: No. Input parsing and assigning variables to each other are two different things. It would be infeasible for a stream to always get it right if it were allowed to just guess at the type you meant.

Comment: By the way, if you were referring to my layout of code, how would you suggest I improve it?

Comment: By making it consistent and logical?

Answer (score 1):

You place both variables on a single `cin`.

It should look like this:
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;

Comment: That will have absolutely no change in behavior. Their problem is trying to pass a decimal (`float`) into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If by a "decimal number" you mean a non-integer, you can't put such in an `int` variable.