# Avoiding infinite loop when a char is enter in place of int

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, cin

I'm doing a Banking System project and need to make sure that every input is valid(program has to be robust). If invalid input is given then user has to enter again.
But when i have a variable of `int` type and user enters `char` type an infinite loop begins.
For example:

```
int i;
cin>>i;
```

If user enters a `char` infinite loop starts. How can i avoid it and ask user for an input again?
Thanks

Comment: Test the state of `cin` after the read. Possibly a simple `if (cin)...` could work.

Comment: Every input valid for a banking system? You'll be the first you know.

Comment: See [Why does my program go into an infinite loop when someone enters an invalid input character?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/stream-input-failure.html).

Comment: @Bathsheba in general i meant to say that my program has to be robust

Comment: you need a *loop* to have an infinite loop...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++, getting a infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002137/c-getting-a-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach that might help; first writing to `std::string` and then going over all elements in the string checking if they're digit. Using header `<cctype> for isdigit()` and `<cstdlib> for std::atoi`, although in c++11 you can use `std::stoi` if your compiler supports it.

If you write: *141.4123*, the result will be *141* after converting (if you let the user type '.'), the result will be *truncated* because you convert to an int.

Working example:

```
int str_check(string& holder, int& x)
{
  bool all_digits = true; // we expect that all be digits.

  if (cin >> holder) {
    for(const auto& i : holder) {
      if (!isdigit(i) && i != '.') { // '.' will also pass the test.
        all_digits = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (all_digits) {
      x = atoi(holder.c_str()); // convert str to int using std::atoi
      return 1;
    }
    else
      return 0;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int x{};
  string holder{};
  while (1)
  {
    if (str_check(holder, x))
      cout << x << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reason for Infinite loop:

cin goes into a failed state and that makes it ignore further calls to it, till the error flag and buffer are reset.

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n'); //100 --> asks cin to discard 100 characters from the input stream.
```

**Check if input is numeric:**

In your code, even a non-int type gets cast to int anyway. There is no way to check if input is numeric, without taking input into a char array, and calling the [isdigit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) function on each digit.

The function isdigit() can be used to tell digits and alphabets apart. This function is present in the  header.

An is_int() function would look like this.

```
for(int i=0; char[i]!='\0';i++){
   if(!isdigit(str[i]))
      return false;
}
return true;
```