# While loop meant to verify user input constantly loops

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to verify the user input, but I have tried two compilers and I either have one of two things happen. Either it will:
-Constantly loop the error message without asking for user input
OR
-Wait for user input, and if the input is incorrect, will constantly loop the error message.

Here is the code:

```
cout << "Input number of the equation you want to use (1,2,3): " ;
cin >> userInput;
cout << endl;

while (userInput <= 0 || userInput >= 4)
{
    cout << "Please enter a correct input (1,2,3): " ;
    cin >> userInput;
    cout << endl;
}

if (userInput == 1)
{
```

userInput is declared as an integer. Is there an easier way to verify user input, or a while loop is necessary? I am still very new to coding.

Comment: Seems straight-forward to me, I don't see an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864540/infinite-loop-with-cin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `int userInput` seems straight forward, it fails when the user inputs non-numeric values. You can use a `std::string` instead and check, if it contains a numeric value

```
std::string userInput;
int value;
std::cout << "Input number of the equation you want to use (1,2,3): " ;
while (std::cin >> userInput) {
    std::istringstream s(userInput);
    s >> value;
    if (value >= 1 && value <= 3)
        break;

    std::cout << "Please enter a correct input (1,2,3): " ;
}
```

---

[`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) is similar to other input streams. It provides input from an internal memory buffer, in this case the value provided by `userInput`.

Comment: This looks great, since it will check any value, not only integers. If you could, can you evaluate what istringstream is, along with "s"? I think I will do it this way but I would like to know what those commands because I am unfamiliar with them

Answer (score 0):

I would add an additional check to make sure that if the user enters non-integral input, the stream is cleared before attempting the next read.

```
cout << "Input number of the equation you want to use (1,2,3): " ;
cin >> userInput;
cout << endl;

while (userInput <= 0 || userInput >= 4)
{
   if ( !cin.good() )
   {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   }

   cout << "Please enter a correct input (1,2,3): " ;
   cin >> userInput;
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: R Sahu: Can you explain what you mean by that? Is that to prevent from the program to infinite loop if user enters a character instead of a integer, or is that a cleanup sort of thing? ....I'm confused, sorry if I don't understand: I am not familiar with cin.good, clear, or ignore

Comment: The first one. Don't be sorry. Seeking clarification when you don't follow a question or answer is essential for productive communication.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a do loop instead so you have less repeated lines

```
int userInput = 0;
do
{
   cout << "Input number of the equation you want to use (1,2,3): " ;
   cin >> userInput;
   cout << endl;
   if ( !cin.good() )
   {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   }
} while (userInput <= 0 || userInput >= 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to cin >> int, if you are to perform any error checking. If the user enters a non-integer, you'll end up in difficult-to-recover-from situations.

Rather, cin into a string, perform any error checking you want and convert the string to a integer:

```
    long x;
    string sx;
    cin  >> sx;

    x = strtol(sx.c_str(), NULL, 10);
```

Comment: If I change the cin into a string, how would I make it verify the user input? Would I need to make a while (userInput isnot 1,2,3) or something of that matter? I don't know how to do that