# std::cin resulting in infinite loop

Tags: c++

Why does the following code result in an infinite loop when entering a character or a string? I've seen questions about it, and the solutions provided in the answers (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864540/infinite-loop-with-cin-when-typing-string-while-a-number-is-expected)), but it does not seem to help at all. The code implements the solutions suggested there, but it still results in an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  while (!(cin >> n)) {
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin.clear();
    cout << std::bitset<8>(cin.rdstate()) << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << std::bitset<8>(cin.rdstate()) << endl;
  }
  cout << n;
  return 0;
}
```

`g++ --version` yelds the folowing: `g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005`

The output of the program is as follows:

```
00000000
00000100
00000000
00000100
... and so on
```

It seems like the value is beeing reentered despite the fact that the stream has been cleared and all input has been ignored.

Comment: That is a *really* strange variant on this I/O code, and I've seen a lot of messed-up stuff. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Originally I just tried to answer another question on SO, using the `while` with the clearing and ignoring - which should just work fine, the loop should terminate when a correct input is given (a number) and it should ask for a number until it gets one. But it never asks for another input - as if the previous one would be still provided. Basically the question contains not the starting point, but the debugging attempts.

Comment: Well, you have ignore and clear mixed up, but this is still weird code.

Comment: Thanks, that changing the order worked for me. Maybe I should consult my rubber duck more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `ignore` before `clear`, but `ignore` only works if the stream has no errors, but it always has at that point.
When you switch both statements it works fine: after one or several invalid inputs, you need 2 consecutive valid inputs to successfully terminate the program.