# What kind of exception should be used to handle data mismatch

Tags: exception, visual-c++, input, primitive-types

I am working on a project where a user enters different types of variables I'm trying to make  my project fool proof so I'm trying to prevent a data mismatch. An example of the type of input that I'm asking the user for would be something like this:

```
int main(){
    int num;
    string name,name2;
    double money
    cout<<"Enter your first name:"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter your last name"<<endl;
    cin>>name2;
    cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"Enter an amount of money you have"<<endl;
    cin>>money;
}
```

I'm main worried about the integer and double types of variables. So I'm wondering if there is a kind of exception for data mismatch for both integer and double variable types?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon on the  4th line . Also look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292202/while-loop-with-try-catch-fails-at-bad-cin-input

Comment: A user entering invalid input is not exceptional.  So do not use an exception, simply parse the response and say that you are sorry for not understanding it.